# Avoid type error from jquery select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to get an attribute from a jQuery selector:

```
var id=$("#nav-titles li.active a").attr("href").replace(/^#/,"");
```

If there are no items from the jquery selector js logs this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined
```

How to avoid this error and store "undefined" (or false, or null) the the id variable?

---

I know I could do this:

```
var id=$("#nav-titles li.active a").length && $("#nav-titles li.active a").attr("href")?$("#nav-titles li.active a").attr("href").replace(/^#/,""):null;
```

But is really necessary to use 3 selectors for a so simple request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to check the `length` of the collection. When `.attr` returns an `undefined` value, the collection is empty. The following snippet uses the `||` operator. When the `attr` returns a falsy value, an empty string is passed.

```
var id = ($("#nav-titles li.active a").attr("href") || '').replace(/^#/,"") || null;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure about if anchor tag exists, this would be more ***readable***

```
 var $anchor = $('#nav-titles li.active a');
 if( $anchor.length > 0 && $anchor.attr('href')){
    id= $anchor.attr("href").replace(/^#/,"");
 }
```

Comment: `$anchor.attr('href').length` not needed - _replace_ fine work on empty string

Comment: @Grundy, you are right, I was supposed to write other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do this for each element you find:

```
var id=$("#nav-titles li.active a").each(function()
{
    $( this ).attr("href").replace(/^#/,"");
});
```